# Less inheritance doesn't work

Tags: css, inheritance, less

Hi can you check please following code? I want define some styles for class, and next apply same styles for another class. I've used inheritance for that but styles from parent aren't used:

```
.parent-item {
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.child-item {
  &:extend(.parent-item);
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the word **all** next to the name of the class

```
.child-item {
  &:extend(.parent-item all);
  //...
}
```

for example

```
.parent-item {
  color: green;
  background: red;
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  &:last-child {
    color: red;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}




.child-item {
  &:extend(.parent-item all);
  //...
}
```

result will be

```
.parent-item,
.child-item {
  color: green;
  background: red;
}
.parent-item:not(:last-child),
.child-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.parent-item:last-child,
.child-item:last-child {
  color: red;
}
.parent-item:hover,
.child-item:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I want extend whole parent style and last item style as well.

Comment: check the code up i updated you have to add the word all next to the name of the class